# Sitecore publishing target disabled

Tags: publish, sitecore, target, production, staging

I'm moving our sitecore production server to a new setup, so have set up a new publishing target for the new server so that I can publish to both old and new during the transition. These are called 'live' (current server) and 'live2' (new server).

I have the new database set up and can switch to it and browse it in the content editor on my staging server.

I have set up a publishing target called 'live2' (by duplicating the existing target 'live').

My permissions (as reported by access viewer) are the same on both 'live' and 'live2' publishing targets.

When I go to Sitecore > Publish (or the ribbon publish button) 'live2' is disabled in the checklist of targets, so I can't publish to it.

The only account with access to publish to 'live2' is the built-in admin account.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 5):

Adam,
The Role/User who should be doing the publishing needs write access to that publishing target.

Can you share the value of the "Security" field for both publishing target items?

Look at the publishing target items and make sure that you are viewing "Raw Values" and "Standard Fields". Can you post up the values? 
Example: `ar|sitecore\Everyone|pe|-item:write|pd|-item:write|`